# Disable out of box features

Tags: 2010, out-of-the-box

In SharePoint we have many options to add different features as shown in attached image, in case we want to remove any of the option listed in attached image, i.e we want to disable them to be used by any user. what could be the ways to achieve them?

Thanks in advance :)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can hide ribbon by using javascript.

```
#ms-designer-ribbon
{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: what about for specific feature?

Comment: First of all, the image that you have posted here is not visible to me... and if you want to disable any specific feature then I think you can goto inspect  option from your browser and find out 'class' or 'id' associated with it. If found, then apply 'display:none' to that 'class' or 'id'. You are Done.

Comment: I want to achieve it on application level not on particular site, this will only help for one site.

Comment: everything you want to hide can be hidden by using css.  And if you want to do it for whole site. then Goto Site settings >Under the heading "Look and Feel", click the link to "Master Page".
In the area for "Alternate CSS URL", select the option "Specify a css file...".
Click the "Browse" button.
Navigate to the "Style Library" folder and select your custom css file. this will apply css to your entire website collection.